# Transform Header and payload to Json nodes

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to enrich payload with some Headers keys and convert to a json structure like that:

```
{
 "Header": { ["key" : "value", "key2": "value"]}
 "Payload": { "attribute" : "value" }
}
```

My gateway is configured like this:

```
    @MessagingGateway 
public static interface MailService {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "mail.input")
    void sendMail(String body, @Headers Map<String,String> headers);        
}
```

Here is my flow:

```
@Bean 
public IntegrationFlow errorFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from(recoveryChannel())
                            .transform("payload.failedMessage")                             
                            .enrichHeaders(c -> c.header(FileHeaders.FILENAME, "emailErrors.json"))
                            .handle(this.fileOutboundAdapter())
                            .get();
}
```

How could I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the whole message to the JSON, you should do something like this:

```
.handle((p, h) -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(new GenericMessage<>(p, h)))
.transform(Transformers.toJson())
```

The trick is like `Transformers.toJson()` doesn't care about headers and transforms only `payload`. So, we have to hack it a bit placing the whole `message` to the `payload`.

Since `ServiceActivator` (ground floor of the `.handle()`) returns `message` as is if the result is `Message<?>` , we don't have choice unless provide `MessageBuilder` and `Transformers.toJson()` will have all the info for your use-case.

Comment: Thats it, Artem,, I'm very grateful. Is it possible reverse the two nodes?  Headers/Payload insteaf of Payload/Headers

Comment: ??? What is the point? They are siblings in the target JSON. Not sure that we can swap that order...

Comment: You would need a custom transformer to transform the payload to a map; if you use a `LinkedHashMap`, jackson would probably iterate in the order you created the map (you can also avoid the timestamp and id headers that way). That said, such ordering is only interesting for "human" consumption.

Comment: My point is only to user-frendly visualization. The files will be consumed by application so the order is not important in case. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So41223173Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So41223173Application.class, args);
        context.getBean("flow.input", MessageChannel.class)
                .send(new ErrorMessage(new MessagingException(new GenericMessage<>(new Foo()))));
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return f -> f.transform("payload.failedMessage")
                .enrichHeaders(c -> c.header("foo", "bar"))
                .transform(toMap(), "transform")
                .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                .handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getPayload()));
    }

    @Bean
    public Transformer toMap() {
        return new AbstractTransformer() {

            @Override
            protected Object doTransform(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
                Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                Map<String, Object> headers = new LinkedHashMap<>(message.getHeaders());
                headers.remove(MessageHeaders.ID);
                headers.remove(MessageHeaders.TIMESTAMP);
                map.put("headers", headers);
                map.put("payload", message.getPayload());
                return map;
            }

        };

    }

    public static class Foo {

        String bar = "bar";

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

    }

}
```

result

```
{"headers":{"foo":"bar"},"payload":{"bar":"bar"}}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. This is sounds useful!.